# Convex function bounded above by linear function

Tags: calculus, functions, convex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^{*+}\to \mathbb{R}$ be a convex function and $g:\mathbb{R}^{*+}\to \mathbb{R}$ be a linear function such that $f(x)≤g(x)$ for all $x>0$ and $f(1)=g(1)$. (Linear : $ax+b$)

It's asked to prove that $f=g$

Graphically it looks logical but still can't find a rigorous proof, I tried proof by contradiction assuming $f(a)<g(a) $ for some $a$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $x < 1 < y$ we have from the convexity condition:
$$
\begin{align}
 g(1) = f(1) &\le \frac{y-1}{y-x}f(x) + \frac{1-x}{y-x}f(y) \\
&\le \frac{y-1}{y-x}g(x) + \frac{1-x}{y-x}g(y) = g(1)
\end{align}
$$
where the last equality holds because $g$ is linear.

It follows that *equality* must hold everywhere in that inequality chain, i.e. $f(x) = g(x)$ and $f(y) = g(y)$.